# Unable to inject resource - most probably incorrect InjectionServices SPI implementation CDI

Tags: java, jpa, junit, cdi, jboss-arquillian

I am following one of the pluralsight tutorials about Java EE. But I encountered problem with testing my app with Arquillian. 
Mayble github will help more (https://github.com/NoWishGranted/personal)
When I did run test case with eclipse i get following stack:

```
Jul 15, 2018 2:30:01 PM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup <clinit>
INFO: WELD-000900: 2.3.5 (Final)
Jul 15, 2018 2:30:02 PM org.jboss.weld.injection.AbstractResourceInjection getResourceReference
WARN: WELD-000834: Unable to inject resource - most probably incorrect InjectionServices SPI implementation: private javax.persistence.EntityManager com.personal.bookstore.repository.BookRepository.em
    at com.personal.bookstore.repository.BookRepository.em(BookRepository.java:0)
```

I suspect that i could have some errors with persistence.xml file, but I don't know if thats true or not. (I am using wildfly and h2 database)

persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">


    <persistence-unit name="bookStorePU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <properties>
            <property
                name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action"
                value="drop-and-create" />
            <property
                name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.action"
                value="drop-and-create" />
            <property
                name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target"
                value="bookStoreCreate.ddl" />
            <property
                name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.drop-target"
                value="bookStoreDrop.ddl" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Book model, without every possible mapping:

```
@Entity
public class Book {

    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(length=200)
    private String title;

    @Column(length=200)
    private String description;

    @Column(name="unit_cost")
    private Float unitCost;

    private String isbn;

    @Column(name="publication_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date publicationDate;

    @Column(name="number_of_pages")
    private Integer numberOfPages;

    private String imageUrl;

    private Language language;


    public Book(){
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Float getUnitCost() {
        return unitCost;
    }

    public void setUnitCost(Float unitCost) {
        this.unitCost = unitCost;
    }

    public String getIsbn() {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setIsbn(String isbn) {
        this.isbn = isbn;
    }

    public Date getPublicationDate() {
        return publicationDate;
    }

    public void setPublicationDate(Date publicationDate) {
        this.publicationDate = publicationDate;
    }

    public Integer getNumberOfPages() {
        return numberOfPages;
    }

    public void setNumberOfPages(Integer numberOfPages) {
        this.numberOfPages = numberOfPages;
    }

    public String getImageUrl() {
        return imageUrl;
    }

    public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
    }

    public Language getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    public void setLanguage(Language language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Book [id=" + id + ", title=" + title + ", description=" + description + ", unitCost=" + unitCost
                + ", isbn=" + isbn + ", publicationDate=" + publicationDate + ", numberOfPages=" + numberOfPages
                + ", imageUrl=" + imageUrl + ", language=" + language + "]";
    }
}
```

BookRepository class

```
public class BookRepository {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="bookStorePU")
    private EntityManager em;

    public Book find(Long id) {
        return em.find(Book.class, id);
    }

    @Transactional(TxType.REQUIRED)
    public Book create(Book book) {
        em.persist(book);
        return book;
    }

    @Transactional(TxType.REQUIRED)
    public void delete(Long id) {
        em.remove(em.getReference(Book.class, id));
    }

    public List<Book> findAll(){
        TypedQuery<Book> createQuery = em.createQuery("SELECT b from Book b order by b.title", Book.class);
        return createQuery.getResultList();
    }

    public Long countAll() {
        TypedQuery<Long> createQuery = em.createQuery("SELECT count(b) from Book b", Long.class);
        return createQuery.getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

Test case class

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class BookRepositoryTest {

    @Inject
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Test
    public void create() {
        assertEquals(Long.valueOf(0), bookRepository.countAll());
        assertEquals(Long.valueOf(0), bookRepository.findAll());
    }

    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
                .addClass(BookRepository.class)
                .addClass(Book.class)
                .addClass(Language.class)
                .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
    }

}
```

pom dependecies

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.CR9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: Can you explain what exactly are you trying to do in BookRepositoryTest

Comment: Just testing if Arquillian is working correctly. Database is empty at this moment so both mehtods should return 0. Naming of the 'create' method is unfortunate and can lead to misunderstanding, sorry for that.

Comment: Ok..then you need to mock the behavior of em.createQuery in order to get proper results..you are not mocking anything here

Comment: Hmm, if you have some time could you explain this in more details?